How to change value from either inside or outside a component
I want to be able to change a value from both inside and outside a component.
Below is a copy of my attempt, from https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/42xrs2
The problem is self documented in the sandbox, here is a copy:

Change from the ouside works if done before change from the inside
Once changed from the inside, impossible to change again from the outside

App.js file:
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import TestParam from "./TestParam";

export default function App() {
  const [outsideChange, setOutsideChange] = useState(null);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setOutsideChange("");
          setOutsideChange("Changed from outside");
        }}
      >
        Change from the outside
      </button>
      <br />
      <br />
      <TestParam testStringProp={outsideChange} />
    </div>
  );
}

TestParam.js file:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function TestParam({ testStringProp }) {
  const [testString, setTestString] = useState(testStringProp);
  useEffect(() => {
    setTestString(testStringProp);
    // alert("in useEffect");
  }, [testStringProp]);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setTestString("changed from inside component")}>
        Change from inside
      </button>
      <h1>Result here: {testString}</h1>
      <p>Change from the ouside works if done before change from the inside</p>

      <p>
        Once changed from the inside, impossible to change again from the
        outside
      </p>
    </>
  );
}


The outside state doesn't actually change because React batches state updates by defaults. When you call
setOutsideChange("");
setOutsideChange("Changed from outside");

the updates are combined, which means that the state isn't cleared and then updated, and see the current and previous states are identical, the value of testStringProp doesn't actually change, and the useEffect is not triggered.
A simple solution would be to change the value you set. For example, replace setOutsideChange("Changed from outside") with setOutsideChange(Math.random()), and you should see it's updating.
If you need static text, you'll need to wrap each set state with flushSync, so each of them would cause a re-render, first clearing the state, and then setting the text.


const { useState, useEffect } = React;
const { flushSync, createRoot } = ReactDOM;

function App() {
  const [outsideChange, setOutsideChange] = useState(null);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          flushSync(() => setOutsideChange(""));
          flushSync(() => setOutsideChange("Changed from outside"));
        }}
      >
        Change from the outside
      </button>
      <br />
      <br />
      <TestParam testStringProp={outsideChange} />
    </div>
  );
}

function TestParam({ testStringProp }) {
  const [testString, setTestString] = useState(testStringProp);
  useEffect(() => {
    setTestString(testStringProp);
    // alert("in useEffect");
  }, [testStringProp]);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setTestString("changed from inside component")}>
        Change from inside
      </button>
      <h1>Result here: {testString}</h1>
      <p>Change from the ouside works if done before change from the inside</p>

      <p>
        Once changed from the inside, impossible to change again from the
        outside
      </p>
    </>
  );
}

createRoot(root).render(<App />);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>




Thanks @Ori Drori, the flushSynch solution works.
I did have to change the firs 2 lines of App.js to
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { flushSync } from "react-dom";

Of course you need to change the destructuirng to imports. I can't use imports in the SO snippets, that's why I've used destructuring to get the functions from the global React and ReactDOM.
